# When do you use “is” and “does” in a question?

Tags: word-usage

When do you use *is* and *does* in a question?

I was talking to a native speaker online and he said something like *What **is** "acting dumb" consist of?* That construction got me confused because it should be *What **does** "acting dumb" consist of?* Then I would answer *It consists of this, and this and that...*

I could be completely wrong but *is* doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: Did he say, "***What's** "acting dumb" consist of?*"? If so, in speech, that means "What does..."

Comment: Hi, studentxxy - did you look up [how to form questions in English](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/a1-a2-grammar/question-forms)?  Any reference on forming questions in English should be able to answer your question.

Comment: I guess it is a matter of understanding that *what's* is a short for *what does*, not of word order used in questions.

Comment: @gotube He did not. He specifically said *WHAT **is** "acting dumb" consist of?* No contractions.

Comment: Notice that, when you say *I was talking,* people usually understand you are speaking to that person or using the sign language to communicate.

Comment: Hi @apaderno As I have mentioned before, I'm not a native speaker, and at this moment I have a very limited vocabulary. But I am curious, what word would better describe "**written communication**"? Conversing? Chatting? Texting? Do you happen to have any other words to offer me?

Comment: *sending messages*, *text-messaging*, and *messaging* would work. As verb, *to chat* could also mean *talk in a friendly and informal way* and it would not make clear you are sending messages.

Comment: Then it's just bad grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A statement

> X is Y.

is transformed to a question

> What is X?

A statement

> X consists of Y.

Becomes, after the insertion of "do support"

> X does consist of Y.

And as a question

> What does X consist of?

In your examples, Y is the quoted phrase "acting dumb".

So the native speaker made a mistake when they said "What is X consist of".  This kind of mistake is not unusual in unprepared speech.

Comment: So, OP is correct that “is” in the quoted sentence was a mistake, and should have been “does.”  I wouldn’t be surprised if the native speaker was talking fast/not enunciating clearly, and OP possibly *misheard* “does” as “is.”

Comment: It could also be that person said *What's "acting dumb" consist of?* and the OP thought *what's* would mean *what is*.

Comment: @apaderno He didn't use any contractions.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Nope. We were actually communicating through text messages.

Comment: @studentxxy In that case, that person used *What is* wrongly.